# How return Partial from Action getJSON

Tags: getjson, partial

I'm having a problem with method using $.getJSON. It's very simple and it looks like that:
Take  ID из DropDownlList CategoryId

```
   <div id="partial" class="editor-label">
            @*  @Html.Partial("");*@
        </div> 

    $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#CategoryId').change(function () {
                        $.getJSON('/Publication/AjaxAction/' + this.value, {},
                          function (html) {
                              $("#partial").html(html);

                              alert("go");
                          });
                    });
                });
```

send in

```
 public ActionResult AjaxAction(int Id)
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                if (Id== 1)
                {
                    ViewBag.SourceTypeId = new SelectList(db.SourceTypes, "Id", "Title");
                    ViewBag.CityId = new SelectList(db.Cities, "Id", "Title");
                    return Partial("_CreateStatya");
                }
            }
            return PartialView();
        }
```

Could you please tell me how to return  Partial in  ??

```
<div id="partial" class="editor-label">
            @*  @Html.Partial("");*@
        </div>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#CategoryId').change(function () {
    $.get('@Url.Action("AjaxAction","Publication")',{id:$('#CategoryId').val()},
 function (html) {
     $("#partial").html(html);
     alert("go");
    },'html');
  });
});

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function () 
{ $('#CategoryId').change(function () 
{ $.get('@Url.Action("AjaxAction","Publication")',
{id:$('#CategoryId').val()}, function (html) 
{ $("#partial").html(html);
 alert("go"); },'html'); 
}); });
```